# why do we need "workspaces" option?

Tags: gnome

in Desktop Environments there is "Workspaces" option, it helps navigating between desktops, but the question is : how is that helpful ? what difference does it make from just minimizing windows and unminimizing it again ? why do alot of people use it ?

Comment: There is no single answer to this question. You're asking for people's opinions, which is more appropriate for a discussion forum than an answers site.

Comment: Generally I would say there is one simple answer: it saves time. When you get used to it and have the grouping of software perfected that is :-D

Answer (score 1):

Consider having 30 different unrelated applications minimized on same workspaces with 4 or more different workspaces, each one containing <10 **related** application.

You can use them to separate your work, one for moving around your system, one for watching stuff, surfing web, coding or doing whatever you're doing.

Also it help you to switch between different jobs really fast, change your workspaces and everything you need is ready there, you don't have to try to find the window, maximize or move it around, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> dozen times to get what you want, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer why I use them: I have a setup with 3 viewports (/workspaces) where

- one is used for personal usage when at home. Watching video's, internet etc.
- the 2nd is used for coding software. I have a group of applications I always use (Aptana, Workbench, SFTP/SSH) and when I launch a script it opens them all on 2
- the 3rd is used to open a group of manuals I tend to need to read. Same: a script opens the browser with all the URLs on 3.

With some fancy keyboard shortcuts it saves me a lot of time. It is quicker to navigate to a python manual open on 3 and back to 2 if I am currently coding in Python. And when I need to switch to Perl or Javascript I open that manual on 3 once and it is open when I need it.
Otherwise I would need to navigate on on workspace through 5 manuals, 5 pieces of software and up to 7 terminals.

What is also the case: when a coworker ends up on my personal system all they see is an empty desktop on 1.